# Change dns values with chrome plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, dns

I want to be able to achieve the same thing as you do with hosts but using a chrome plugin. I'm not sure if theres one available.

Essentially, I want to point a url to a specific IP address that's not listed on the web.  I don't want to use the hosts file because I want to make this as easy as possible for my clients.

Is there a plugin out there or a solution that is contained within a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

This is DNS:

```
I want to point a url to a specific IP address
```

However, this:

```
that's not listed on the web.
```

causes questions. You could generate random names in DNS to obfuscate what you're doing, but anything you present as a client based solution where the client doesn't have to do this work will need to be translated, whether you reinvent the wheel from scratch or use a solution that's already available.